# Reading from serial port in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I want to use VB.NET to read from a serial port. I use VB to write to the COM3, and in the next line I read from COM3. However, when I read from the com port and write to the console, I do not see anything.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim returnStr As String = ""
    Dim com As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
    Try
        com = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM3")
        com.ReadTimeout = 10000

        com.WriteLine("test1")
        Dim Incoming As String = com.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine(Incoming)
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Finally
        If com IsNot Nothing Then com.Close()
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()


End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Are you expecting to read what you wrote? The idea is that you would be communicating with something else, e.g. a hardware device, on the other side of the port. It would read the data that you write and vice versa. What are you actually connecting to?

Comment: Ultimately I want to run a C# program that reads what is written to the serial port by my VB program, as a means for the two programs to communicate.

Comment: A `SerialPort` is an unusual way to do that. Have you considered alternatives?

Comment: I considered writing to a memory address via pointers, but this was not very straightforward. I just need to send a string from one program to the other.

Comment: It might be worth your while to [read this](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net).